# Как отметить имеющиеся checkbox'ы сформированные в `foreach`

Tags: php, html, массивы, циклы, checkbox

Есть 2 массива: массив checkbox'ов (формируется в foreach) и второй массив выбранных чеков, по размеру они разные. Как мне отметить имеющиеся?

```
{foreach $brands as $key=>$brand}
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="{$brand->tag_id}"
      {if $res_brands[$key]->brand_tag_id == $brand->tag_id}checked=""{/if}
      name="brand_tag_id[]"> {$brand->name}
    </label>
  </div>
{/foreach}
```

Из-за того, что два массива разные по количеству, ключ здесь не актуален.

Answer (score 1):

Шаблонизатор ваш не знаю и структура `$res_brands` не известна, но предложу заменить

```
{if $res_brands[$key]->brand_tag_id == $brand->tag_id}checked=""{/if}
```

на

```
{if isset($res_brands[$brand->tag_id])}checked=""{/if}
```

или на

```
{if !empty($res_brands[$brand->tag_id])}checked=""{/if}
```

если у вас в `$res_brands` и для отключенных checkbox состояние `false` хранится.

Или

```
{if in_array($brand->tag_id, $res_brands)}checked=""{/if}
```

если в `$res_brands` просто список номеров.

Comment: Благодарю, это подошло - {if $brand->tag_id|in_array:$res_brands}checked=""{/if}